Correlation between Yield Curve PCA components and Level - Slope - Curvature
I found a piece of the following book:
Yield Curve Modeling and Forecasting
That states that when extracting the PCA components from the yield curve and projecting the data along these axis we find a very strong correlation between:

Yield projected along the first axis and the 10Y yield (shift)
Yield projected along the second axis and the 10Y-6M spread (slope)
Yield projected along the third axis and the 6M+10Y-2*5Y butterfly spread (butterfly)

I know this is "classic" theory of yield curve modelling, but I wanted to check it by myself. The data used can be found at the following link: Nominal Yield Curve - Board of Governors. I used the SVENPYXX columns (Par Yield) from 1st Jan 85 to dec 08 as stated.
I ran the following code:
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import pearsonr 


#Read File and drop na_rows
df=pd.read_excel('feds200628.xlsx',index_col=0).dropna()

#Fit a PCA on 3 components
pca = PCA(n_components=3)
pca.fit(df)

#Projection on PCA components
projected = pd.DataFrame(pca.fit_transform(df))
eigen_vectors=pd.DataFrame(pca.components_).transpose()
eigen_vectors.plot()

#Correlation analysis
correls=[]
correls.append(pearsonr(projected[0],df['SVENPY05'])[0])
correls.append(pearsonr(projected[1],df['SVENPY10']-df['SVENPY01'])[0]) 
correls.append(pearsonr(projected[2],
                        df['SVENPY01']+df['SVENPY10']-2*df['SVENPY05'])[0])

I get the following plot for my PCA components

Which is the "classical" Shift-Twist-Butterfly graph - but my correlations are way lower than what we can see in the book.
As you can see on page 12, projected data and respectively 10Y yield, 10Y - 0.5Y spread, 10Y+0.5Y-2*5Y seem to be "strongly" correlated:

Diebold and Li Forecasting Term Structure through a similar approach also find strong correlations (0.97, -0.99, 0.99):

My correlations are the following:
-0.99: Satisfying
-0.96: Satisfying
-0.44 => ??
Not sure what I do wrong, and why do I find such a low correlation with my butterfly component. Note that instead of using the 0.5Y I used the 1Y as the 0.5 was not in the data.

are you using curve levels or daily changes?

I am using curve levels. From my understanding this is what they do on the papers I provided.
Am I wrong on this one?
Trying with daily changes - I get 0.71 as a correlation for the third factor (which is - indeed relatively better).

I don't use covariance of absolute levels for the reason it is inconsistent with financial market option pricing theory, and am always skeptical of any results that do use it. See this answer: https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/50931/29443

Standardize your daily changes.
