PCA on yield curve - Matlab
Consider that I have a dataset of 8964 daily observation of US yields from 1990 to May 2024. These yields are related to each maturity from 3 months, every 3 months, to 30 years, for a total of 120 maturities, so that the matrix $y$ is $120\times8964$.
My purpose is to evaluate the main factors that can affect the yield curve, i.e. the level, the slope and the curvature, but, in particular, I would like to analyse the factors that affect the movement of this curve ($dr$).
For this reason, I just applied the command [coeff, scores, vlambda] = pca(y'); on Matlab, where coeff should be the matrix of the loadings.
About this, I have two questions:

Should I use y' or cov(diff(y',1,1)) as input of PCA ? The second option represents the matrix of the daily changes (first difference) of the interest rates for each maturity. I was wondering about using this as input, because I saw from the literature that maybe it is the right way to perform the PCA on the yield curve.

Suppose that I have my matrix of loadings coeff and I'm interested in seeing what is the effect on the price of a 30 years coupon bond, which pays coupons every 6 months, due to a movement in the interest rate term structure $dr$. Then, can I say that the second element in each of the loading vectors is linked to the 6-months interest rate, which is the first relevant element for that bond? For instance, the same would hold for the 4th element on the loading vector that would correspond to 1-year maturity and so to the second relevant element of the bond.



I don't use covariance of absolute levels for the reason it is inconsistent with financial market option pricing theory, and am always skeptical of any results that do use it. See this answer:  quant.stackexchange.com/a/50931/29443

Some duplication with https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/80340/correlation-between-yield-curve-pca-components-and-level-slope-curvature

Is 100°F twice as hot as 50°F? (I assume these are US treasury yields, interpolated from observed bonds.) Suppose that in 1981, the 10Y jumps from 15% to 13.5%; and in 2020 it jumps from 3% to 1%. Are these jumps comparable?

The US treasury yield curve has been derived directly from the parameters provided from  https://www.federalreserve.gov/pubs/feds/2006/200628/200628abs.html so I don't know exactly the original bonds features.
